# How do I mark a Java EE component as mandatory?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I am building a Java EE web app. Occasionally I get errors like these

> JBAS011006: Not installing **optional** component com.example.MyServlet
>   due to exception: [..]DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054:
>   Could not find default constructor for class

However, com.example.MyServlet is very much essential to my application. How do i mark it mandatory?

Edit: com.example.MyServlet ; I did not include it previously because I wanted a general answer.

```
/**
 * Class to use JSR299 in ServiceLocators
 */
@WebServlet(value = "/gwtRequest", name = "InjectingRequestFactoryServlet")
//<!-- You'll need to compile with -extras and move the symbolMaps directory
//        to this location if you want stack trace deobfuscation to work -->
@WebInitParam(name = "symbolMapsDirectory", value = "WEB-INF/classes/symbolMaps/")
public class InjectingRequestFactoryServlet extends RequestFactoryServlet {
    @Inject
    public InjectingRequestFactoryServlet(InjectingServiceDecorator serviceDecorator) {
        super(new DefaultExceptionHandler(), serviceDecorator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `com.example.MyServlet` provide a default constructor? JBoss is probably mentioning it as optional because it is actually not required to get the server running.

Comment: It has a public n-arg-constructor annotated with @Inject. I did not include the code, because i wanted a more general answer not tailored to that specific servlet class.

Comment: Its just a warning.. everything should work fine as expected..hopefully it is fixed in next JBoss release

Comment: err... no?
when i get the warning, injections are null